# Mysql calculation with condition

Tags: mysql

I have the following calculation:

```
select *, (pergroup + (perguest *  (4 - guests_included))) as calculated
```

This works fine as long as guest_included is not bigger then in this case 4 (4 is the number of guests the user selected, a variable..)
In normal code I can use a ternary like this for that part:

```
persons - guests_included > 0 ? persons - guests_included  : 0;
```

where persons would be 4 in this case.

How would one solve this in MySQL?

Comment: this question is confusing ... `4` is actually `persons`?

Comment: right, sorry @DanFarrell if this was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer explicitly without a clearer definition of what your inputs and expected output is correct, but as I understand you want `persons - guests_included` to never be below 0.

In that case, you might be able to use [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to add a lower bound to the value:

```
select *, (pergroup + (perguest *  GREATEST((persons - guests_included),0)) as calculated
```